# UIPickerView interactive area for tapping cut off in iOS 7

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios7, uipickerview, uipicker

When I make a long picker with multiple components, only the components near the center react to the tap-to-select feature.

For example, if you want to pick the very next row under a selected row, you should be able to just tap it to make it animate up into the selection area.  This feature still exists with iOS 7, but the area with in the UIPicker that will actually accept the tap is a very small window, no larger than 200px.

Is there any way to expand this tap-able area to include the entire UIPickerView, so any time you tap a row it becomes the selection?

**EDIT here is the code, it's pretty standard...**

```
    - (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component{

    NSLog(@"picked %i %i" , component , row);
}


- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView {
    return 4;
}

- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    return 15;
}

- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component{
    return @"";
}

- (UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view
{
    UILabel *pickersLabel;

    pickersLabel =[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, view.frame.size.width , view.frame.size.height )];
    pickersLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"thing %i" , row ];


    pickersLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    pickersLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:1/255.0 green:1/255.0 blue:2/255.0 alpha:0.05];

    pickersLabel.opaque = NO;
    [view addSubview:pickersLabel];
    return pickersLabel;
}
```

Comment: I think there is some other issue...please put you code at here..

Comment: Dipen, I added the code.  I also created an entirely new project just eliminate all the varables.   It still only allows you to tap to select a row in the very center of the UIPickerView.  The code above is from that test project.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I've had massive problems with UIPickerViews that were in .xibs instead of Storyboards in iOS 7. I'm not sure if there's some optimization going on behind the scenes in the Storyboard or if this is a straight-up bug, but it's worth a shot - I'm using a picker view that's coming from a Storyboard right now and I am able to tap on non-selected rows and they scroll up and become selected.